# PySpark filter all rows with word in column if column value is array

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a table like this

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Hello    | [{"id": 3, "name": "John"}, {"season": "spring", "country": "America"}]  |
| Bye      | [{"id": 4, "name": "James"}, {"season": "summer", "country": "Canada"}]  |
...
```

I want to filter any row with "season": "summer" before writing it to a new location.

I have tried:

`data_frame.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").filter(dataframe.columnb=='summer').save("file://path")`

and

`data_frame.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").where(dataframe.columnb!='summer').save("file://path")`

but because Column B is an array these do not work. How do I read the array of Column B to filter out the rows that have "season": "summer" in PySpark?

Comment: which databricks you are using azure,aws,community?

Comment: For databricks, I am using aws

Comment: what's the data type of `columnb`? `Array<Struct<>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to `explode` the json array data first so that we can easily search the key.

You code will look like this

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(Column_A='Hello', Column_B=[{"id": 3, "name": "John"}, {"season": "spring", "country": "America"}]),
    Row(Column_A='Bye', Column_B=[{"id": 4, "name": "James"}, {"season": "summer", "country": "Canada"}])
])

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df_explode = df.select(F.col('Column_A'),F.col('Column_B'), F.explode(F.col("Column_B")).alias("data_explode"))
df_explode.filter(F.col('data_explode')["season"]=='spring').select(F.col('Column_A'), F.col('Column_B')).show(truncate=False)


+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Column_A|Column_B                                                         |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Hello   |[{name -> John, id -> 3}, {country -> America, season -> spring}]|
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please note that here the expectation is your `Column B` is data type of `Array(map)`.

Please check this [Live Notebook](https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/jupyter/user/apache-spark-w3z7inz1/notebooks/python/docs/source/getting_started/filter_json_key.ipynb) Running Example